# Error ORA-00905 al crear tabla

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy empezando a modelar una base de datos. Empecé primero con una tabla (después podría agregar más elementos) pero al ingresar el código a SQL Developer aparece este error:

```
Informe de error -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

La tabla tiene este código:

```
CREATE TABLE MULTI_TBL_TD (
    idTd DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    nomTienda VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    modTienda LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    stkTienda LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MULTI_TBL_TD_PK PRIMARY KEY (idTd)
)
```

El software SQL developer me indica que el error "empieza en la línea: 2 del comando :".
Qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Qué es `LONGVARCHAR`? Nunca he visto este tipo antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es sencillamente que estás usando tipos que no existen en Oracle.

En este caso, el error es por el tipo `DOUBLE`. Asumo que la intención en este caso es usar `BINARY_DOUBLE`.

Pero una vez que arregles ese problema, verás que el siguiente error será con el tipo `LONGVARCHAR`, <strike>que francamente, ni te puedo sugerir una alternativa, porque no entiendo cual es tu intención.</strike> Buscando un poco, parece que tal vez te refieres al tipo `LONG VARCHAR` en la base de datos `Derby`, que es básicamente un `VARCHAR` sin límite máximo. De ser el caso, el equivalente apropiado en Oracle sería `CLOB`.

Asegúrate de limitarte a los tipos listados aquí: [Oracle Built-In Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLQR/sqlqr06002.htm#SQLQR959).

Comment: Comencé modelando en SQL Power Arquitect, lamentablemente acá no están los tipos que usa Oracle (o tal ves no haya configurado bien este software). Al menos, de entrada solo NUMERIC, INTEGER. Si reemplazo estos tipos por tipos de valor aceptados en Oracle, se crea la tabla sin problemas.